# RxJs Observable.empty().delayWhen() not delaying

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I want to pause an observable if an error occurs to allow the user to decide to continue. When an error occurs values are skipped. Here I only ask the user every three errors.

`Observable.empty().delayWhen(...)` is behaving just like `Observable.empty()` but `Observable.empty().delay()` works as expected and so does `Observable.of(null).delayWhen(...)`.

```js
Subject = Rx.Subject
Observable = Rx.Observable

let i = 0
let subject = new Subject()
  
onFailure = () => {
 // simulate prompting user to continue
  setTimeout(() => {
    subject.next(null)
  }, 3000)
}
          
Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
      .concatMap(num => {
        return Observable.fromPromise(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         num == 8 ? resolve(num):reject()
        }))
          .catch(err => {
            console.log('rejected '+num)
            i = i % 3; i++;

            if (i < 3) return Observable.empty().delay(500)  // this works
            
            // I don't want to return null but Observable.empty() wont work with delayWhen...
            return Observable.of(null).delayWhen(() => {
              console.log('prompting user...')
              return Observable.create(observer => {
                onFailure()
                subject.take(1).subscribe(() => {
                  console.log('continued after waiting...')
                  observer.next(Observable.empty())
                })
              })
            })

          })
      })
      .subscribe(num => {
        console.log('got '+num)
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.8/Rx.js"></script>
```

Expected:

```
 rejected 1
 rejected 2
 rejected 3
 prompting user...
 continued after waiting...
 rejected 4
 rejected 5
 rejected 6
 prompting user...
 continued after waiting...
 rejected 7
 got 8
 rejected 9
```

(the `got null` values should not occur)

Note:

I tried `retryWhen()` followed by `retry(someNumber)` but the problem is I need to retry forever so I don't think its the correct operator here.

Answer (score 0):

ok so I actually solved it by realizing `retry()` went forever...

```
.retryWhen(errObs => {
    return errObs.mergeMap(err => {
      i = i % 3; i++;

      if (i < 3) return Observable.throw(err)

      return Observable.create(observer => {
        console.log('prompting user...')
        onFailure()
        this.subject.take(1).subscribe(() => {
          console.log('continued after waiting...')
          observer.next(Observable.empty())
        })
      })
    })

  })
  .retry()
```

But its still odd behavior from `Observable.empty().delayWhen(...)`